# Does MOXy have an analog of Jackson's @JsonIgnore tag?

Tags: json, jersey, jax-rs, moxy

In a JAX-RS (Jersey) application, I have a Java class whose instances can be both stored in a SQL database (using OpenJPA) and sent over the wire as JSON text (in a RESTful application). This class has a a field that has a setter and getter (for use with OpenJPA), but which I don't want to be converted to JSON. I know that if I were using Jackson for the Java-object-to-JSON conversion in Jersey, I could use the the @JsonIgnore tag to achieve this purpose, viz.

```
// This is the main class sent in REST responses; inside a Parent description, a number of 
// Child instances are described
@XmlRootElement(name = "parent") 
@Entity  
public class Parent  {
   ...
    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Vector<Child> children = new  Vector<>();
   ...
}

@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {
...
    // Don't want to serialize Parent, to avoid an infinite loop!
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Parent parent;
    public Parent getParent() { return parent; }
    public void setParent(Parent _parent) { parent = _parent; }
...
}
```

However, my Jersey setup uses the "default" JSON conversion tool, which is MOXy rather than Jackson (as per https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html , sec. 9.1). So this setup does not have the `@JsonIgnore` tag. Is there an analogous tag in the Jersey + MOXy framework? I thought `@XmlTransient` may do the trick, but it does not.

As a practical solution, I simply renamed `getParent()` to `xgetParent()`; apparently OpenJPA is not affected, but MOXy does not try to convert this field anymore. But that's a ridiculously kludgy solution of course, and is bound to break something eventually.

Comment: If you don't have any restrictions, I highly recommend using Jackson as your JSON provider. If you can't, for MOXy, @XmlTransient _should_ work. Make MOXy is actually the JSON provider being used. The word "default" is confusing and is only applicable in a few cases. In any case, Use Jackson if you can. It's pretty much the de-facto JSON library for Java and has more features, a larger community, better support, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`@XmlTransient` works, but with getter. I tested it with EclipseLink/MOXy 2.7.7.

So try

```
@XmlTransient
public Parent getParent() { return parent; }
```